# How to find all possible substrings in a string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

What I would like to do is take a string and return all possible substrings that are greater than length 2.  So using the `welcome` example:

```
we
el
lc
co
me
wel
elc
lco
com
ome
welc
elco
lcom
come
and so on.....
```

The only way I could think to do it was something like this (totally untested):

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++) //i is starting position
{
   for (int j = 2; j + i < word.Length; j++) //j is number of characters to get
   {
       wordList.Add(word.SubString(i, j));
   }
}
```

But I'm wondering if there a better way to do this (using LINQ possibly) that I don't know about?

Comment: That's the exact way I'd do it... Although, wouldn't you want to start i at zero?

Comment: That's true for the first loop.  I'd have to test to be sure about the rest, but I think since I don't want 1 letter substrings I need to start at 2.

Comment: You might also want to check for uniqueness in wordList ? e.g; if your string is "mememe", then the substring 'me' appears multiple times

Comment: By better I mostly mean shorter (one liner?), but I would also take more efficient or something without a nested loop.

Comment: @RJ Lohan, Good point on uniqueness.  Due to the bigger picture of this application I would probably do this after the entire word list was created with a `Distinct()`

Comment: To enforce uniqueness, use a `HashSet<string>` rather than a `List<string>`.

Comment: I think there's a bug in your code - inner loop needs to terminate on j+i <= word.Length

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How's this for a simple, readable approach?

```
var text = "welcome";

var query =
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, text.Length)
    from j in Enumerable.Range(0, text.Length - i + 1)
    where j >= 2
    select text.Substring(i, j);
```

It produces:

```
we 
wel 
welc 
welco 
welcom 
welcome 
el 
elc 
elco 
elcom 
elcome 
lc 
lco 
lcom 
lcome 
co 
com 
come 
om 
ome 
me
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `where` if you make your second `.Range` start from `2`

Comment: @AakashM - I certainly could have removed the `where j >= 2` by changing the second `Range` to be `Enumerable.Range(2, text.Length - i - 1)`, but that makes the function of this query less obvious. It would short circuit a few iterations, but it's all in memory and it is very fast either way.

Answer (score 4):

This LINQ solution should work:

```
var str = "welcome";
var items = Enumerable
    .Range(0, str.Length)
    .SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Range(2, str.Length-i-1).Select(j => str.Substring(i, j)))
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(s => s.Length);
foreach (var s in items) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. this is where I find the loop-based approach is more clear and readable :-) Although Linq might work in this problem, it's not as readable(which is one of the Linq's strong points) as loop-based approach

Comment: @Hao Absolutely! LINQ solution to a problem this simple is a mere curiosity - just to show that LINQ is powerful enough to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The code is as follows:

```
   internal static List<string> GetAllSubstring(String mainString)
    {
        try
        {
            var stringList = new List<string>();
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mainString))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < mainString.Length; i++) //i is starting position
                {
                    for (int j = 2; j + i < mainString.Length; j++) //j is number of characters to get
                    {
                        if(!stringList.Contains(mainString.Substring(i, j)))
                        {
                            stringList.Add(mainString.Substring(i, j));
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            return stringList;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return null;
    }
```